# How to install Screenlets on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: software-installation, 16.10, screenlets

How do I install [Screenlets](https://launchpad.net/screenlets) on Ubuntu 16.10? It failed to install as the Terminal keeps telling me "unable locate package".

```
sudo apt-get install screenlets
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package screenlets
```

Comment: check if the PPA is installed

Comment: @junLyeap Have you found your answer for 16.10? Did the existing answer help?

Answer (score 6):

**Why another answer:** *With anwar's answer you will not get cool update while shubham arawkar's answer is for Ubuntu 16.04 not 16.10(OP's choice). So I'm providing a solution to take care of both the issues.*

The Screenlets PPA provides numerous screenlets (desktop widgets), such as RSS readers, weather, clock, countdown, a Conky-like system information widget, folder view, calendars, sensors, and much more.

Install Screenlets in Ubuntu 16.10:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:screenlets/ppa
sudo sed -i 's/yakkety/xenial/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/screenlets-ubuntu-ppa-yakkety.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install screenlets screenlets-pack-all
```

Done now go to dash and type `screenlets` and choose whatever screenlets you want.

Some snaps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Screenlet project has been dead for a long time: that's why you can't find packages for this for 16.04 or later. The latest non-EOL Ubuntu that has the `screenlets` package is Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr).

I have old versions of the package downloaded already and I installed them now to see if they still work in 16.04. Surprisingly most of them work!

So here is the process you can follow to install them. ***Note***, I didn't test this on 16.10 and I'm not **sure** it will work, but IMHO, it will.  **;-)**

1. Download the older debs for `screenlets` and `screenlets-pack-all`

   - `screenlets` http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/screenlets
   - `screenlets-pack-all` http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/screenlets-pack-all
2. Install the downloaded debs using `dpkg`. There will be dependency errors but we'll fix them in step 4. Assuming you downloaded the deb files in your home, the command will be:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i screenlets*.deb
   ```
3. Now fix the dependency errors (if any) with this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```

this will install additional required packages not satisfied with manual installation via `dpkg`.

Here is a screenshot of my desktop with some screenlets working.

[image: screenlet working on 16.04]